# I don't know why this code is stop when I put "abcedfghij" to this code

Tags: arrays, c, loops, visual-studio-code

I trying to copy Char array elements to Int type array.... I defined size as 10 but when i put 10 character (a ~ j),the code is stop and get out from running...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 10
int main(void){
    char charr[size];
    printf("input your string\n");scanf("%s", charr);
    printf("%s", charr);

    int arr[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        arr[i] = (int)charr[i];   
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what number is `size`?

Comment: A `char` array of size 10 can hold a string of up to 9 characters because one character is needed for a terminating NUL (`\0`) byte. Entering more than 9 characters will write past the end of the array which is undefined behavior.

Comment: `"abcdefghij"` takes 11 characters to store your input and the terminating 0 byte. This does not fit into your `char[10]` and you trigger a buffer overflow causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Always restrict entry length to a buffer: *always*. `scanf("%9s", charr);` If you really want to avoid hard-coding that `9` you can create a format string on-the-fly at runtime using `sprintf()`.

Comment: Also, if you input fewer than 9 chars, you'll still be reading indeterminate values from `charr` since it's not been initialized.